# FullCalendar: Set event end in drop function

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, droppable

I have the ability to drag and drop external events to the calendar with the default behavior of start time being where the event was dropped. I would like to set the default behavior to also set the end time for the event to be 1 hour after the start time. This seems trivial but I can't seem to get it working. Below is my drop function (essentially the droppable items demo plus 1 line.)

```
drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a
    // reference to the same object
    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

    // assign it the date that was reported
    copiedEventObject.start = date;
    copiedEventObject.end = date.setHours(date.getHours()+1); // <- should be working
    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

    // render the event on the calendar
    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks"
    // (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
    $(this).remove();
    }
},
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Joe Chin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in that example for what you're trying to do is that `allDay` is set to true, so it ignores the hours specified in the start date.  If you were happy with say the time being midnight - 1am as the default, here's what you could do:

```
var tempDate = new Date(date);  //clone date
copiedEventObject.start = date;
copiedEventObject.end = new Date(tempDate.setHours(tempDate.getHours()+1)); // <-- make sure we assigned a date object
copiedEventObject.allDay = false;  //< -- only change
....
```

**EDIT: OK, I actually tried this version.**  It seems to work.

Comment: hi Ryley, thanks for the feedback, while the allday property might cause problems, I do not think its the root cause of my particular situation. It looks like start is set to a date in the format of (Fri Nov 12 2010 09:30:00 GMT-0800 (PST)) while end is set to a date in epoch time. Im in the process of converting end from epoch to UTC. If you have any tips I'd appreciate them.

Comment: @JoeChin - see my edit above, I actually tested it this time, seems to do the right thing...

Answer (score 1):

Calendar property

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/defaultEventMinutes/
sets de default end time from start

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the solution posted by Ryley to work properly. It would place the external event at the header of the calendar and when I viewed the week, the event would be a thin line (it appeared collapsed) or not appear at all. This may be a fullCalendar version difference (I'm using v2 of fullCalendar). In v2 of fullCalendar I was able to get this to work without any problems of the event within any of the calendar views.

```
drop: function (date, jsEvent, ui) { // this function is called when an external element is dropped.

    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

    var sdate = $.fullCalendar.moment(date.format());  // Create a clone of the dropped date.
    sdate.stripTime();        // The time should already be stripped but lets do a sanity check.
    sdate.time('08:00:00');   // Set a default start time.
    copiedEventObject.start = sdate;

    var edate = $.fullCalendar.moment(date.format());  // Create a clone.
    edate.stripTime();        // Sanity check.
    edate.time('12:00:00');   // Set a default end time.
    copiedEventObject.end = edate;

    // render the event on the calendar
    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

},
```

Answer (score 0):

Above version 2, "eventReceive"-event called after dropped.

> Called when an external draggable element with associated event data was dropped onto the calendar. Or an event from another calendar.

Then use "event.setEnd(date);" to change end date.

```
eventReceive: function (arg) {
 var endDate = .....
 arg.event.setEnd(endDate);
}
```

Documentation eventReceive: [link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive)

Documentation setEnd: [link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setEnd)